# Addiding variable in Header function in PHP

Tags: php, variables, url, header-files, html-entities

I want to add one more variable in the header function but I am not getting the correct syntax.IN the given header one variable htmlentities($result->uin) is there i want more variable(htmlentities($result->Name)) to pass along with this .

```
header("Location: viewrequest.php?uin=" . htmlentities($result->uin);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the other variable like you did the first one, you just have to use an ampersand `&` to separate them. Also, use urlencode to encode url parameters not htmlentities

```
header("Location: viewrequest.php?uin=" . urlencode($result->uin) . '&name=' . urlencode($result->Name));
```

Comment: But it is not carrying the value new url is without uin and name value

Answer (score 0):

You can use `http_build_query` to build and encode the query string for you:

```
header('Location: viewrequest.php?'. http_build_query([
    'uin' => $result->uin,
    'name' => $result->Name,
]));
```

[PHP.net Manual - Function Reference - `http_build_query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')'

Comment: it is going to next page but the url is not carrying any value .URl is http://localhost:81/SMS/admin/stationerypdf.php? only